# Set and unset custom_attributes for checkout fields if empty or not in WooCommerce

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce

Inside my function I'm trying to do something like this:

```
if ( !empty( $fields['billing']['billing_phone'] ) ) {
    $fields['billing']['billing_phone']['custom_attributes'] = array('disabled'=>'disabled');
  }
  elseif ( empty( $fields['billing']['billing_phone'] ) ) {
    // Here's my problem. I don't know how to unset, disable or delete that array previously added.
  }
```

What I want to archive here, is that, if the field is empty the user should be able to add information for the first time only.

Thanks!

**My own solution:**

Important: Don't forget to delete/ignore the previous code (that method didn't work for me).

I just added this javascript in the checkout page.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $('input[name*=billing_phone_no]').map(function()
{
   if( $(this).val() ) {
          $(this).attr("disabled", 'disabled');
          $(this).addClass('notactive');
    }
});
        });
```

**CSS:** Besides the background color, it seems that this is not necessary, you could try without the CSS.

```
input.notactive {
    background: #eee !important;
    pointer-events: none;
    cursor: default;
}
```

**Multiple inputs**

If you need to do the same for multiple inputs at the same time, you can change this line:

```
$('input[name*=billing_phone_no]').map(function()
```

for this one:

```
$('input[name*=billing_phone_no], input[name*=billing_phone_digt_countrycode], input[name*=billing_email]').map(function()
```

Maybe this is not the perfect/cleanest solution, If you know how to improve this, please let me know :)

**Still looking for help:** Is anyone knows the PHP/functions method for this that would be perfect!

Comment: if i understand your correctly then you need to use JavaScript to achieve that

Comment: Thank you @kashalo , just found a possible solution for this using JS. I'm not sure is this is the perfect solution. But it's doing the job.